# SQL column not found although it exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm using the Laravel framework to create a prototype and need to output an individual article from a database based on it's ID. Seems straightforward but I keep getting the following error when I query the database:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'articles.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `articles` where `articles`.`id` = 1 limit 1)
```

I'm trying to retrieve a specific article based on the database column `article_id` via the articles table in my Article model. I am using a resource route thus the method name 'show' - so I can access via `article/{$article_id}`  in the URL.

Here is my controller:

```
public function show($article_id) {

    $article = Article::find($article_id);
    $article->toArray();

    return view('articles.view', array('article' => $article));

}
```

There is no `articles.id`. It should be `articles_id`. Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks in advance, any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The find command looks for whatever is set as the primary key, which by default is `id`. You can change the primary key in your model:

```
class Article {

    protected $table = 'articles';
    protected $primaryKey = 'articles_id';

}
```

Comment: Thanks Aynber, that has fixed - simple when you know how!

Answer (score 2):

`find()` searched by primary key, so change the query to:

```
$article = Article::where('article_id', $article_id)->first();
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey - good to see correct syntax for future reference although I have changed default primary key name in the model as suggested by Aynber.